# “an die Tafel” vs “an der Tafel”

Tags: difference, preposition

> 1. Ich schreibe an **die** Tafel.
> 2. Ich schreibe an **der** Tafel.

Are they both correct? And what’s the difference?

Comment: 1) isn't quite correct. You'd only use this in combination with a direct object as well: *Ich schreibe den Satz/die Aufgabe/es/...  an die Tafel.*

Comment: @KilianFoth  okay , and the second sentence wouldn‘t need a direct object ?

Answer (score 11):

They are both correct.

The difference is:

- *Ich schreibe an die Tafel* means I write something onto the blackboard (or whiteboard, depending on the setup).
- *Ich schreibe etwas an der Tafel* means I write something while standing at the blackboard. It is not necessary to use the blackboard in that sentence, I could also write something to a sheet of paper while standing there.

The first stresses the action of writing to a blackboard, the second stresses my position when writing something (that still MIGHT be writing on the blackboard, but not necessarily).

Comment: Oh , i see . Now it‘s clear . Thank you Torsten 

Answer (score 9):

German has nine **dual-way prepositions**, these are *an, auf, hinter, neben,   in, über, unter, vor and zwischen*. For those nine prepositions (and only for those), the preposition+accusative means a different thing than preposition+dative. With verbs of motion, this is usually the difference between direction and position.

> Ich gehe an den Strand. *(accusative)*

*I walk to the beach.*

> Ich gehe am/an dem Strand. *(dative)*

*I walk on the beach.*

The exact meanings depend on the verb. For *schreiben*, it's

> Ich schreibe (etwas) an **die** Tafel. *(accusative)*

*I write (something) onto the blackboard.*

> Ich schreibe an **der** Tafel. *(dative)*

*I write at the blackboard.*

Comment: Thank you Janka for the comprehensive explanation , i already studied the Wechsel Prepositions , but you know , there‘s always exceptions ( Ausnahmen ) that need an explanation , schwimmen and tanzen for example , not regarded as motion for the German . German Preposition is always a nightmare to me  

Comment: As English ones are for German speakers.

Comment: Uh? Schwimmen and tanzen are perfectly regular motion verbs. *Ankommen* for example isn't. Maybe you mistake *direction* as *motion*?

Comment: Well , i’m not really sure but i remember my German teacher once told me , “ we , the Germans don’t regard the See as a room “ so when someone swim in the see , this action is don’t regarded as a “ Bewegung “ !!

Comment: *Erst schwimmen die Fische in das Netz, danach schwimmen sie im Netz.* This is direction vs. position.